# Importing Illustrator XML into excel Error: -1072896636

Tags: xml, svg, adobe-illustrator, excel-2016

**Context:**

I have been on a mission to use Illustrators "variable data" function for about two months now.

The documentation says "hand it off to your developer, they will give you a spread sheet". Which may be the case for other designers, I however do not have a developer available to help me.

My ultimate plan is to figure out what the "layout" or "format" for an excel spread sheet should be in for it to be successfully converted into a XML that Illustrator can read. More on that at the bottom.

**Question:**
I created a super complicated Email marketing newsletter analytics info graphic that uses variable data. "captured" my data set and then exported it from Illustrator. It gave me an XML, I try to import said XML into Excel, I get the error "Error: -1072896636 DTD is prohibited" How can I fix this?

**What I already did:**
Not knowing what could possibly be the issue I made a more simple document with only 9 object. 3 of which were set to "text variables" 3 of which are set to "Visibility variables" and the last 3 are me attempting to set them as BOTH text and visibility variable. (3 objects, each one being a "visibility variable" and a "text variable" at the same time, so 6 variables for 3 objects) When i tried to import the XML from that file i got the same error. I tried to google the issue and checked here, and there was a similar question for a non Illustrator XML and apparently they are different. The solution i found over and over was to "remove the line referring to a DTD". Which then gives me a different error that "&ns_flows; is undefined".

I tried other avenues, such as using a third party importer. Long story short these wont work either because they use sub layer names to set variables. This prevents a single object from being both VIS variable and TXT variable, which is not prohibited by illustrator.

I did some trial and error, and found the way I should place objects on the spreadsheet in excel in order to get pretty close to what I want using an online "spreadsheet to illustrator XML" converter. It works and gives me something illustrator can read, but I can not figure out how to make it clear to the converter what the variable type is. It makes all things TXT variables. I know this by reading the XML it gives me. (I have very little knowledge of code and can understand some of what I am reading in most languages)

**The XML Code from simple file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
]>
<svg>
<variableSets  xmlns="&ns_vars;">

<variableSet locked="none" varSetName="binding1">

<variables>

    <variable varName="TextOneTXT" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="TextTwoTXT" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="TextThreeTXT" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="VisableOneVIS" trait="visibility" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="VisableTwoVIS" trait="visibility" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="VisableThreeVIS" trait="visibility" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="BothOneGreen" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="BothOneRed" trait="textcontent" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

    <variable varName="BothOneGreenVIS" trait="visibility" category="&ns_flows;"></variable>

</variables>

<v:sampleDataSets  xmlns:v="&ns_vars;" xmlns="&ns_custom;">
<v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="Data Set">

<TextOneTXT>
    <p>Im the first</p>
</TextOneTXT>

<TextTwoTXT>
    <p>not</p>
</TextTwoTXT>

<TextThreeTXT>
    <p>im the third</p>
</TextThreeTXT>

<VisableOneVIS>
    true
</VisableOneVIS>

<VisableTwoVIS>
    false
</VisableTwoVIS>

<VisableThreeVIS>
    false
</VisableThreeVIS>

<BothOneGreen>
    <p>3</p>
</BothOneGreen>

<BothOneRed>
    <p>3</p>
</BothOneRed>

<BothOneGreenVIS>
    true
</BothOneGreenVIS>

</v:sampleDataSet>

<v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="Data Set 1">

<TextOneTXT>
    <p>not</p>
</TextOneTXT>

<TextTwoTXT>
    <p>Yo Fifth</p>
</TextTwoTXT>

<TextThreeTXT>
    <p>not</p>
</TextThreeTXT>

<VisableOneVIS>
    false
</VisableOneVIS>

<VisableTwoVIS>
    true
</VisableTwoVIS>

<VisableThreeVIS>
    false
</VisableThreeVIS>

<BothOneGreen>
    <p>2</p>
</BothOneGreen>

<BothOneRed>
    <p>2</p>
</BothOneRed>

<BothOneGreenVIS>
    false
</BothOneGreenVIS>

</v:sampleDataSet>

<v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="Data Set 2">

<TextOneTXT>
    <p>true</p>
</TextOneTXT>

<TextTwoTXT>
    <p>dat</p>
</TextTwoTXT>

<TextThreeTXT>
    <p>yo</p>
</TextThreeTXT>

<VisableOneVIS>
    true
</VisableOneVIS>

<VisableTwoVIS>
    true
</VisableTwoVIS>

<VisableThreeVIS>
    true
</VisableThreeVIS>

<BothOneGreen>
    <p>1</p>
</BothOneGreen>

<BothOneRed>
    <p>1</p>
</BothOneRed>

<BothOneGreenVIS>
    true
</BothOneGreenVIS>

</v:sampleDataSet>

</v:sampleDataSets></variableSet></variableSets></svg>
```

Comment: I tried some more things, nothing came of it. I even talked to some people on other websites. I guess this one is just impossible then?

Comment: To go from CSV to Illustrator, keep using VariableImporter.jsx, just manually bind the (only the visibility ones) variables on art or layers. You only will have to do it one time during setup, then you can re-import the data and the bindings will stay, so long as your variable names and count stay the same.

Comment: The only problem there is, that im still left witht the problem of it not being easily changed then. 

The point of making this into a variable data project in the first place was so that i can just quickly edit the fields and it update them in the graphic.

I can bind them manually in illustrator just fine, which is what your solution is, but then when i export to try and get to a format i can easily edit. (goal is a spread sheet) then I am again back to where I left off.

Comment: Yea, you update in spreadsheet, re-import and you're done, no binding again, etc. Unfortunately there is no live-linking, but the VariableImporter at least consolidates the actions to just the spreadsheet edits and an import. The preset feature makes it even faster to produce similar kinds of jobs.

Comment: What I'd like to ask is, why are you wanting to export the populated data out of AI to be edited elsewhere? The variable data workflows in PS, AI and ID all in one form or another have the 'one way trip' as the method -as in, you edit the text data and keep re-putting it in vs the other way around. AI is unique that it lets you update datasets and re-export an XML file (which you can technically edit and re-import), but like you mentioned, spreadsheet is easiest.